# Grouping in ListView in Virtual mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a virtual listview and added some items to it, but now i want to assign them to a group.

for example how to do this when RetrieveVirtualItem is executed. // just my opinion

I am using visual studio 2010

I want to use the native listview and i am in a position where i can't use 3rd party components.

Comment: Potentially helpful [CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35197/Undocumented-List-View-Features#virtualgroups).

Answer (score 4):

Officially you cannot use groups in `Virtual` mode. [CLR 2.0 Virtual ListView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cumgranosalis/archive/2006/03/06/virtuallistviewusage.aspx)

However, this project uses an undocumented feature (on Vista and higher) that enables groups in `Virtual` mode. [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/features.html#groups-on-virtual-lists)